# What's the point of Accessors in BotBuilder V4?

Tags: botframework

During the bot builder v4 preview release I was able to get my state through the turnContext like so:

```
var state = await turnContext.GetConversationState<MyConversationState>();
state.CounterState.Count++; // state updated... no other steps
```

Now with the non preview release I have to setup accessors to get my state making the whole process very convoluted, like so:

```
var state = await _accessors.CounterState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CounterState());
state.TurnCount++;
await _accessors.CounterState.SetAsync(turnContext, state);
await _accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(responseMessage);
```

I understand how to use and implement the accessors I just get the use in them. Can someone explain why the second method above is better than the first? In the first method I had a state class that held all my data that I could manage within that class. Now from what I understand that class that I had before becomes an accessor?

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use accessors if you do not need/want to.  They exist so that developers can expose only the properties they want to expose to specific components of their application.

An example could be if you were collecting personal data about a user in your app but had to pass off your state to be read/write to another component of your application that does not need the user's personal data. You can expose pieces of your state without exposing everything via accessors.

If you do not need this security/functionality you do not need to use accessors.